# Saving the last execute mysql(i) statement to execute again

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**REQUEST:** I need to store the last execute statement (MySQLi) for later execution in a next loaded page

**DESCRIPTION:** I have made a search form
as you might already know, the search pages should paginated.
I have done all of the settings required for the a search result page to work. it works. but it looks a little weird to me. let me explain...

When a user performs a search, the search form takes her/him to the search result page, and then a list of results are shown. this is ok....

**PROBLEM:** but when she/he clicks on the another page of the search result, for instance the second page, for the page to work, it has to AGAIN set the $_POST settings and perform the search AGAIN and  offset the result to the current page and then render it. Except offsetting, which is a necessity of pagination, other operations are just a repetition.

I need something like execute_last() or execute_again() to execute the last performed execution. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do so?

No.

By the way, for search you should use GET method, not POST.
Neither you should store parameters in a session, but pass them via query string again